# Show "loading" userform whilst another userform runs a routine in the background

Tags: vba, userform

I have a series of userforms (the intention is that there will be no interaction with spreadsheets) and i need one userform to run script in the background whilst another userform/window pops up and lets the user kmnow that the operation will take some time.

This is used in multiple instances (e.g. combobox_change with a label updating its value based on a loop that goes through 25k-30k lines).

I have tried:

1. code as per below (which throws back an error as (i believe) there can be a modal=True and Modal=False userform running concurrently:
   z_loading.Show vbModeless

z_loading.StartupPosition = 1

'additional vba routine here

Unload z_loading

2. restructuring the location of code

- Step 1: changing combobox or clicking button shows z_loading userform
- Step 2: z_userform_initialize contains the vba code and ends with unload z_loading
- Step 3: Another userform populates based on z_loading_initialize code
  The problem with the above is that when the user closes the userform coming after is, it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - found the solution.

Modal was true for all userforms. By making modal false the .vbmodeless method works.